# stereo_mode=left_right metadata tag vanishes

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube, metadata, stereo-3d

I try to add the metadata tag stereo_mode=left_right to a *.mp4 file I want to upload on YT. I use ffmpeg and and either I tried to set it using 
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -metadata stereo_mode=left_right -codec copy out_met.mp4
or added it through a metadata txt file like 
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i met.txt -map_metadata 1 -codec copy o_met.mp4
I can add tags like "title" or "artist", that are displayed when I try to retrieve the metadata with 
ffmpeg -i o_met.mp4 -f ffmetadata m.txt
or 
ffprobe o_met.mp4
or the mediainfo tool but the f*** stereo_mode tag vanishes and is not shown by any program!!!
Is it maybe not implemented like documented?
http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Metadata
Or is it not supported in avi and mp4 files? Is it still there but not displayed?

while writing the file it is correctly displayed in the console output:
Output #0, mp4, to 'o_met.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : 3dvideo
    stereo_mode     : left_right
    artist          : FFmpeg troll team
    encoder         : Lavf58.27.103

but later while retrieving it is not anymore!!!
 Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    title           : 3dvideo
    artist          : FFmpeg troll team
    encoder         : Lavf58.27.103

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation you linked, the metadata is related to the Matroska muxer. 
If you try the example mentioned there, using .webm as output, you get the metadata in the file.

```
$ ffmpeg -i input_file.mp4 -an -c:v libvpx -metadata stereo_mode=left_right -y stereo_clip.webm

$ ffmpeg -i stereo_clip.webm -f ffmetadata
...
Metadata:
  stereo_mode     : left_right
  HANDLER_NAME    : VideoHandler
  ENCODER         : Lavc58.35.100 libvpx
  DURATION        : 00:00:28.600000000
Side data:
  stereo3d: side by side
```

So it's related to the muxer you are using.